# Batch for mysql dump - exclude some table based on SELECT

Tags: mysql, database, batch-file

We have a hundred tables on our database, the data of twenty of these tables are generated thanks to a `LOAD DATA INFILE`
(there is therefore no point in us saving them with a `MYSQLDUMP` knowing that they are the heaviest - around 80% of the size of the database)

These `LOAD DATA INFILE` are managed using a PHP form, the names of the tables are therefore saved in the database like this :

- **Name of the table** : import_table
- **Columns of the table** : table_name, table_column, date_creation, etc ...

So when I make this query :

```
SELECT table_name FROM import_table
```

I have this result:

```
list_of_customer
all_order
all_invoice
...
```

I would therefore like, thanks to this table containing all the tables to ignore (and which can change at any time) create my batch in order to perform `MYSQLDUMP`

So I did that :

```
@ECHO OFF
"C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql8.0.18\bin\mysqldump.exe" mydatabase --result-file="C:\test1\test2\databases.sql" --user=**** --password=****
```

**How can I integrate my `SELECT table_name FROM import_table` in order to use the option `--ignore-table` ?**

Comment: Can you add a stored procedure that dumps the tables and invoke that instead of doing all the work in a script file?  Otherwise, you have to save the query result to a file, then parse that file to build up the dump command line.

Comment: I did not understand too much, create a stored procedure for the MYSQLDUMP? Note that this is a production database, I cannot empty the tables and leave too long a waiting time for users

Answer (score 1):

1. Take of table_name in a file
2. Read that file in variable
3. Use that variable for --ignore-table

```
@ECHO OFF

"C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql8.0.18\bin\mysql.exe" mydatabase -e "SELECT group_concat(table_name) FROM import_table" --user=**** --password=**** > queryresult.txt

set /p ExcludedTables=<queryresult.txt

"C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql8.0.18\bin\mysqldump.exe" mydatabase --result-file="C:\test1\test2\databases.sql" --user=**** --password=**** --ignore-table-=%ExcludedTables%
```

I can't test as I am on mac but I hope you get the idea about how you can do it.

Comment: Thank but I have an error : ``mysqldump: Couldn't find table: "group_concat(table_name)"`` Indeed on the first line of the file I have "group_concat (table_name)" then the list of tables, how to delete this line?

Comment: are able to execute raw query separately "SELECT group_concat(table_name) FROM import_table" ?

Comment: Yes it works and I have a comma separated list of tables, suddenly I don't understand why I have this first line on the text file